# PencilKit, Layer and how to zoom in

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I can add some layers([PKCanvasView]) for my drawing and I can zoom in, but this is working only at the top layer.

But how I can add the zoom to all of my layers?

I added to each on the PKCanvasView the delegate and handle with

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? { ... }
```

but the effect is only at the top view.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not really. I added an array to save all drawings in one canvas view. And then I am adjusting the array for different effects.